# error : Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

Tags: vue.js, graph, nuxt.js, chartist.js

I'm trying to make a graph with libraries on nuxt

I'm looking to use chartist but it doesn't work for now.

Link chartist: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html

I'm trying diplay the diagram by following the get started part.

In my component, i'm doing this:

```
<template>
  <canvas class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth" />
</template>

export default {
  created() {
    this.creatChart();
  },
  methods: {
    creatChart() {
      const data = {
        // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
        labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
        // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
        series: [
          [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
        ]
      }
      const chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);
      return chart;
    },
  },
}
```

And i receive this error : Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

Of course chartist is installed with npm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `created() {}` to init your Chartist, you must use the `mounted() {}` method to init your chart only on client side.

```
mounted() {
  this.creatChart();
},
```

The "created" hook will be run twice once on server-side, then once on client-side. The "mounted" will be run only once on client-side.

Chartist is only available on client-side (browser), due to the usage of `document.querySelectorAll`.

But on server-side (Node.js), `document` does not exist... which  explains your error of `Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null`.

Comment: If it solved your issue, please mark this answer as valid in order to help other developers ;-)